# where is chrome CSS Reference

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

There are CSS references available for [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-SW1) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS), is there a similar reference for Chrome?

Comment: I don't think Chrome has a CSS Reference, believe it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None is provided by Google.  Since Chrome and Safari both use the webkit engine, the developers probably assumed that the [Safari CSS Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Introduction.html) would suffice.

You might consider contributing to the [Webkit documentation](http://www.webkit.org/projects/documentation/index.html) effort (Webkit is an open source effort).

Answer (score 1):

[MDN CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference) is the best place to look.  WebKit CSS support can be found in the browser compatibility tables on the individual pages.  MDN also contains a [Webkit CSS Extensions Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference/Webkit_Extensions).

Still, it is not perfect.  Chrome-specific values to shared properties are not always listed.  For example, there is an entry for [`-webkit-appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-webkit-appearance), but `slider-vertical` is not contained in the [list of valid values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance#Values). I don't know of an official source where this value was discovered.