# How to know whether a CSS3 property is standard or not?

Tags: css

Is everything on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp) standard and not for anything out? Our project is using CSS3:Zoom property for some svg images, [someone says](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/) it is non-standard. Is there any reference about that? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recomend checking the relevant CSS specifications at w3c.org (http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss#specifications). However, something being standard doesn't mean that it's supported by all browsers. And also if all/some browsers support it doesn't mean it's standard.

EDIT:
Some links to reference of relevant browsers' implementations and the their CSS support:

MS for IE:

- [Windows Internet Explorer API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/hh828809%28vs.85%29)
- CSS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/ms531209(v=vs.85)

Mozilla for Firefox:

- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/)
- CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Google for Chrome: [where is chrome CSS Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188780/where-is-chrome-css-reference)

Apple for Safari:

- [Supported CSS Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-SW1)
- [Introduction to Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001267-SW1)

Comment: I'm kind of accepting this answer. It seems more worth to see whether it is supported by all browsers than see if it is "standard" or "non-standard". Make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: The CSS spec is what ultimately defines whether something is standard or not. I think that pointing to it does answer the question, which starts with 'How to know'.

Answer (score 1):

When using w3schools, always check the browser compatibility section (there should be a section where the browser icons are shown, with some crossed out if the property is incompatible).

I would also highly recommend http://caniuse.com/, which is the go-to tool for many developers.

And no, `zoom` is not standard in many browsers (including Firefox). Use CSS Transform instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the link is awesome. Still a little bit confused. Does that mean if one property is compatible for all browser, it is a standard one? Otherwise, not?

Comment: Well, that tends to be a more useful definition as the W3 guidelines aren't always followed. Sure, as @frozenkoi mentioned, the "standard" is set by W3, but I rarely use this as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

For ZOOM , transform:scale(X); is the standard.

Watch out if using zoom and transform:scale() in IE9, it can apply both,
serve zoom to IE8 and lower only :).

Comment: A comment, not an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

“CSS3” is a collective name for any specifications, drafts, and proposals on CSS beyond CSS 2.1. There is no official definition for what is official in it, but a common and reasonable interpretation is that W3C documents on CSS are “official” if they are W3C Recommendations or Proposed Recommendations or Candidate Recommendates, with decreasing level of completedness.

The page http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work lists CSS-related W3C documents, but it has had errors: some documents have been omitted, some have been presented with wrong status info, and there have even been dysfunct links. But it’s a good starting poing. You just need to check the documents themselves for their status (and content).

I have compiled a [CSS keyword index](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css/keywords.html) which contains “official” and proposed property names (and other CSS names). It is in no way official, but it may help as a fast track to locating relevant information.

For example, the `zoom` property is defined in [CSS Device Adaptation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt/), a Working Draft, newest version September 2011. So it’s certainly not standards. Working Drafts are just drafts, some of them mature, some just sketchy. The drafts themselves carry the boilerplate text “This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.” This particular draft is not making much progress – drafts that are actively worked on are typically updated at least once a year.

According to Sitepoint.com CSS info (an unofficial but useful compilation), [`zoom`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/zoom) is supported by IE from version 5.5, not supported by any other browser. In effect, it has been an IE-only property, most often used just as `zoom: 1` to work around certain IE bugs (the hasLayout issue) without actually wanting any zooming. But nowadays it is also supported in WebKit browsers like Chrome, so you can use it for real zooming if it is sufficient to have support in IE and in sufficiently new versions of WebKit browsers.

The w3schools is not an authority of any kind, not even a useful reference or tutorial; see http://w3fools.com